# Before install EOSIO, Why install the Graphviz?

Tags: eosio-code, eosio.cdt

To my knowledge, Graphviz shows the code graph tool. But I haven't found the code graph in 'eos' directory.

So I want to know the reason. And How can I use the graphviz in EOSIO?

Comment: Which version of EOS.IO have you installed?

Comment: i have installed 1.7.4 version